# Get id of link that created modal box?

Tags: jquery

I need some way to get the id of the llink that created a modal box, or set an id within the created modal box. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `id`? And showing the code you're using to trigger the modal box would be a great help to us, in helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery [.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store arbitrary information.

e.g

```
$('#container').delegate('a', 'click', openModal)

function openModal(){

  //code to open dialog

  //store id of clicked anchor on dialog
  $('#dialog').data('anchor', this.id)


};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the modal box in an event handler for the link, you can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) feature to stash its id:

```
$('a.open-dialog').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').data('openedBy', this.id).dialog();
});
```

Then `$('#dialog').data('openedBy')` will return the id of the link that opened the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a jQuery click event you can use the keyword this, which refers to the triggering element for the event. It would then be a trivial this.id to get the id. But without the triggering code we can only guess.